# Change a toggle switch check to true or false

Tags: javascript, html

I have a toggle switch like this one:
[image]

And the `Active` label is coming from a database. I want this button to be changed to `true` if it's active.

This is what I've tried so far:

**HTML**

```
<input onclick='toggleStatus(this)' type='checkbox' id='{{ db.id }}' name='{{ db.id }}'>
<label id='user-status-toggle' for='{{ db.id }}'>{{ db.status }}</label>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function toggleStatus(radio) {
    var toggle = document.getElementById('user-status-toggle');

    if (radio.checked) {
        toggle.textContent = "Active";
        radio.checked = true;
    } else {
        toggle.textContent = "Inactive";
        radio.checked = false;
    }
}
```

It's working, but only when I interact with the button. When I first visit the page, it's always toggled off, even if the status is Active. Note that I may have multiple buttons and their status may vary between `Active` and `Inactive`.

So how should I do this?

Comment: What language/library are you using in the HTML?

Comment: I'm using PHP but I avoided it because it has convoluted syntax and I went with something simpler as an example.

Comment: You’ll likely need to render a checked attribute in the php rather than relying on JS to do it

Answer (score 1):

You can set initial `checked` on your `<input />`

just add `checked` attribute.

for example,

```
// if this one is what you want initial checked..
<input checked onclick='toggleStatus(this)' type='checkbox' id='{{ db.id }}' name='{{ db.id }}'>
<label for='{{ db.id }}'>{{ db.status }}</label>
<input onclick='toggleStatus(this)' type='checkbox' id='{{ db.id }}' name='{{ db.id }}'>
<label for='{{ db.id }}'>{{ db.status }}</label>
```

I don't know about PHP well, but I guess it would be work..

```
// if this one is what you want initial checked..
<input checked='{{ db.textContent === "Active" }}' onclick='toggleStatus(this)' type='checkbox' id='{{ db.id }}' name='{{ db.id }}'>
<label for='{{ db.id }}'>{{ db.status }}</label>
```

Comment: This will be checked even if my label `textContent` is `Inactive`

Comment: @Klein-_0 I edited the answer.

Comment: It didn't worked, but you gave me a good idea, so I fixed it. I don't know how reliable it is, but I'll edit my question with the fix.

Comment: @Klein-_0 I fixed my last answer, `'active'` => `"active"`. could try this again?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by checking if the `db.status === "Active"` first with an if-else statement in PHP:

```
if (db.status === "Active")
{
    return <input checked onClick=toggleStatus(this)'>
}
else
{
    return <input onClick=toggleStatus(this)'>
}
```